# While inserting data from one table to another table getting error

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have one sproc, in that Only one insert statement , in which I am inserting data from one table to other table. It has 1.2 million records. I got below error

> The instance of the SQL Server Database Engine cannot obtain a LOCK
>   resource at this time. Rerun your statement when there are fewer
>   active users. Ask the database administrator to check the lock and
>   memory configuration for this instance, or to check for long-running
>   transactions.

But there were no locks at that time on table. So when I ran the sproc again it ran successfully. I found that, it is related to memory as mentioned in this article, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337440.aspx . Any one have more info on it. As I am not inserting data in Temp table, then how it is related to memory?

Comment: SQL-Server needs memory for locking

Comment: @CPMunich can you please elaborate